# invalidcastexception was unhandled c# error after input

Tags: c#, math

im trying to calculate an equation using a simple program but when i try to run my code im getting this exception

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
```

i have no idea what i am doing wrong the equation seems to be ok but thats where the errors are being generated this the equation im trying to code
[image: my equation image]

and this is my code below

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double  r = 0;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            r = (((Math.Sqrt(2) * Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text)) /(2* Math.PI * Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text))) * (1/Convert.ToDouble(textBox2) +1/Convert.ToDouble(textBox1)) );
            label7.Text = "R1 = " + r.ToString() + " ohms/km";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: textBox2.Text! and textBox1.Text! Be careful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you have this at the end of your long line:

```
(1/Convert.ToDouble(textBox2) +1/Convert.ToDouble(textBox1))
```

That needs to be `textBox2.Text`, since you can't convert a textbox object to a double.

Also for readability sake, it'd be worth not doing all the conversions in one line, and instead doing them one at a time into separate variables then using those. It'd also make you less likely to suffer from this type of problem since it'd be clearer where it's going wrong.